# Mock_redis not working ok when running 2 tests but works when running them isolated

Tags: rspec, redis, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have the following tests that uses mock_redis to stub the Redis installation. (I'm using Rails 5.1.4)

Both tests expects that by calling the method with 2 different parameters, in both cases a new key is going to be added to Redis.

```
describe '#paper_version' do  
  before do
    @redis_instance = MockRedis.new
    allow(Redis).to receive_message_chain(:new).and_return(@redis_instance)
  end

  it 'stores the reduced version on Redis Cache when paper_type == reduced ' do
    foo.paper_version('reduced')
    expect(@redis_instance.keys).to include "reduced_paper_#{foo.id}"
  end
  it 'stores the full version on Redis Cache when paper_type == full ' do
    foo.paper_version('full')
    expect(@redis_instance.keys).to include "full_paper_#{foo.id}"
  end
end
```

If I run just one of them, everything works and test passed without issues, but If I run both, the second one always fails with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@redis_instance.keys).to include "full_paper_#{foo.id}"
   expected [] to include "full_paper_97"
```

Any ideas of why this could be happening?

---

My gemlist:

```
rails (5.1.4)
rspec-core (3.7.1)
rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
rspec-rails (3.7.2)
rspec-support (3.7.0)
mock_redis (0.17.3)
```

Comment: can't reproduce, something is happening in your code or not getting torn down between tests?

Comment: Thanks for trying @Anthony. I'll keep debugging and try to find out :)